# Functions that will return a common identity for combinations of n elements?

Tags: algorithm, combinations

For example, say we have a set of elements {e|e>=0,e<32}
then function f with
parameter1  `ary`: an ary of elements whose combinations will be represented.It is assumed that elements of `ary` will not be repeated
parameter2  `len`: the length of array `ary`.
should return the same value for all arrays containing the same elements as `ary`, regardless of the sequence the elements are arranged

```
int f(int[] ary,int len){
     int idnt=0,i;
     for(i=0;i<len;i++){
          idnt|=1<<ary[len];
     }
     return idnt;
}
```

My question is: what are other functions/algorithms with similar utility?

Comment: Does it need to be reversible? As in, do you also need to be able to input this identity and return an array?

Comment: Any function at all whose first step consists of sorting the elements.

Comment: @Geobits: No,there are only two requirements for the output of the function: 1. The function returns the same result for inputs containing same elements. 2. The function returns different results for inputs of different set of elements. Although provided that these two are met, and that the algorithm is known, it should often be possible to write a function to reverse the process, whose should contain the same elements although might be in different sequence, after all, sequence is not of any concern here.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: True but we also need an algorithm to encode the sorted list into a short data type for comparison with other sets

Comment: @Elkmouk: And for that, any function at all that takes two elements of a given type and returns another element of that type: for example `+`, `-`, `*`, `XOR`, `AND`, `OR`.